# How can I mark a row when it meets a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
              'name' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
              'john_01' : [1, 2, 3],
              'mary_02' : [4,5,6],
                 })
```

I'd like to attach a mark '#' with the name if column['name'] equal to list containing 'A' and 'B'. Then I can see something like below in the result, does anyone know how to do it using pandas in elegant way?

```
name_list = ['A','B','D']  # But we only have A and B in df.

   john_01  mary_02 name
0        1        4   #A  
1        2        5   #B
2        3        6    C
```

Comment: Is `name_list` and `name` the same length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If name_list is the same length as the length of the Series `name`, then you could try this:

```
df1['name_list'] = ['A','B','D']
df1.ix[df1.name == df1.name_list, 'name'] = '#'+df1.name
```

This would only prepend a '#' when the value of `name` and `name_list` are the same for the current index.

```
In [81]: df1
Out[81]: 
   john_01  mary_02 name name_list
0        1        4   #A         A
1        2        5   #B         B
2        3        6    C         D

In [82]: df1.drop('name_list', axis=1, inplace=True) # Drop assist column
```

If the two are not the same length - and therefore you don't care about index - then you could try this:

```
In [84]: name_list = ['A','B','D']

In [87]: df1.ix[df1.name.isin(name_list), 'name'] = '#'+df1.name

In [88]: df1
Out[88]: 
   john_01  mary_02 name
0        1        4   #A
1        2        5   #B
2        3        6    C
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use `df.loc[row_indexer,column_indexer]` operator with `isin` method of a `Series` object:

```
df.loc[df.name.isin(name_list), 'name'] = '#'+df.name
print(df)
```

The output:

```
   john_01  mary_02 name
0        1        4   #A
1        2        5   #B
2        3        6    C
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isin` to check whether the name is in the list, and use `numpy.where` to prepend `#`:

```
df['name'] = np.where(df['name'].isin(name_list), '#', '') + df['name']

df
Out: 
   john_01  mary_02 name
0        1        4   #A
1        2        5   #B
2        3        6    C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

def exclude_list (x):
    list_exclude = ['A','B']
    if x in list_exclude:
        x = '#' + x
    return x

df = pd.DataFrame({
              'name' : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
              'john_01' : [1, 2, 3],
              'mary_02' : [4,5,6],
                 })                

df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda row: exclude_list(row))

print(df)
```